# Exception when adding a View from non activity class

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

I'm trying to manipulate the layout when something is clicked, and to do that I have to use a Handler Class. The problem is I can't do that without getting this message:

[image: Screen capture of the error message]

Here is my code. (I'm using C#/Xamarin.android)

```
public class ClickListener : VectorElementEventListener
{
    MapView mapView;
    MainActivity activity;

    public ClickListener(MainActivity activity)
    {
        this.mapView = activity.mapView;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public override bool OnVectorElementClicked(VectorElementClickInfo clickInfo)
    {
        var zoomIn = activity.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.zoomIn);
        zoomIn.Text = "+"; // The exception originates from this line

        return true;
    }
}
```

Those two lines work fine if they're placed in the MainActivity class. Why is that?

I've been stuck on this for too long. Please help!

Comment: please provide your error log to help , but I dont think you can called FindViewById<> in no-Activity class , you can pass view reference

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it. Here's the solution:
If we want to make changes on the UI, we should use an Action and run it on the main activity UI thread. Like this:

```
public class ClickListener : VectorElementEventListener
{
    MapView mapView;
    MainActivity activity;

    public ClickListener(MainActivity activity)
    {
        this.mapView = activity.mapView;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    public override bool OnVectorElementClicked(VectorElementClickInfo clickInfo)
    {
        Action manipUI = () => {
            var zoomIn = activity.FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.zoomIn);
            zoomIn.Text = "+";
        }
        activity.RunOnUIThread(manipUI);
        return true;
    }
}
```